# How to fix 'rake --tasks' error: "rake aborted! undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby

How can I stop `rake --tasks` from aborting? Has 'split' been deprecated?

It is outputting this error... ([full trace](http://pastie.org/8389155))

```
[rake --tasks] rake aborted!
undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
/Users/Crimbo/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:297:in `first_sentence'
.
.
.
```

Lines in question... `task.rb` ([full text](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/blob/f4ed5a6b459f2a5080977a18ec904a0acc0210df/lib/rake/task.rb))

```
296    def first_sentence(string)
297      string.split(/\.[ \t]|\.$|\n/).first
298    end
299    private :first_sentence
```

---

ruby '1.9.3', engine: 'jruby', engine_version: '1.7.5' | rails (3.2.14) | rake (10.1.0)

Comment: AFAIK `nil` never had `split` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The split method is not deprecated. But in your case the string seems to be nil. Please check what you are passing to the method first_sentence.

**EDIT:**

This seems to be an issue in rake gem itself. Please check this url,

https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/issues/220

But, the gem owner feels that this is valid and suggests the users to use `rake -T --all` instead.

---

**Patch Solution**

If you wish to still use `rake --tasks`, follow what *Amit Thawait* stated...

Use `to_s` method in the `task.rb`, so that it does not throw the error `undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass`

```
def first_sentence(string)
   string.to_s.split(/\.[ \t]|\.$|\n/).first
end
private :first_sentence
```

Comment: I cannot tell. I have now found that if I just execute `rake`, it returns `rake aborted! - Don't know how to build task 'default' - org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in 'each'...`

Comment: Is it possible to post the entire rake file as an edit in the question?

Comment: Sorry, I just realised you cannot run `rake` command without passing any parameters, so please ignore my previous comment

Comment: rake has to be performed with the task name as the argument.

Comment: I have now added a link to the file in the question

Comment: I have now added a link to the full trace in the question. Adding "to_s" seems to fix it, but surely the average user should not need to do that. I am now trying to find out if this problem is unique to me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38873/discussion-between-vamsi-krishna-and-crimbo)

Answer (score 1):

As a safety measure, you should use `to_s` method, so that it doesn't throws error as `undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass`

```
def first_sentence(string)
  string.to_s.split(/\.[ \t]|\.$|\n/).first
end
private :first_sentence
```

Comment: This seems to fix it. I still do not know why I have to manually edit it seeing it is the rake gem, and I have not seen anyone else have the same problem. Looking over the commits, the line was added 5 months ago (27 April 2013 - rake-10.1.0.beta.3)